# Ubuntu 18.04 x86_64 packages missing in APT

Tags: apt, package-management, 18.04, architecture

so I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my Intel NUC and whenever I try to install some package I am getting an info that it is missing / Unable to locate.

E: Unable to locate package openjdk-8-jre

E: Unable to locate package ncdu

I checked and can see that package https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/ncdu is not available for x86_64... Why this architecture is not supported? is it temporary? or should I start looking for a different distribution?

thanks!